# Deny access to the site, based on QUERY_STRING

Tags: regex, .htaccess

My site is "under attack" : bots from many different IPs are filling a form with spammy content.

IP addresses can't be filtered, they are always different, so I was thinking to filter by QUERY_STRING, to match an URI like this:

```
www.site.com/search?field1=spamword&field2=another_spamword
```

The rule :

```
rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)spamword(.*)$
rewriterule .* - [F,L]
```

The regular expression looks right, but the rule is never executed.
Any idea what's going on?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you enabled & looked at your `RewriteLog` ?

Comment: Just a note: the form I'm talking about is a search form, so no captcha could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not enable the rewrite log, so I have found another way, and did this directly on all the pages with a form:

```
if ( strlen( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )>650 ) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized'); 
    .. error message to not panic real users ...
    exit;
}
```

Because I have found ( watching the access logs and considering the form fields ) that an URL longer than 650 characters is never a valid request. (the average size was 4-6 Kb)

Sadly the regex issue is still there, and did not managed to solve it.
But at least the issue was partially solved ( the bots are still there, but the page uses very few resources, as no queries are done )

Luckily the bots will recognize the 401 error and desist.

Answer (score 0):

Aside of @Wrikken comment (check the log and see if `RewriteEngine` is `on`), the only thing that can be wrong is the regex. Try removing the ():

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*spamword.*$
```